# Identifying a PHP problem that doesn't prints a ERROR and the code isn't yours

Tags: php

I've to make a website works and I don't know what to do right now. I can run it in a virtual machine with Ubuntu, on my company's server in Debian, on a WAMP... but I can't get it working in a server from a client.

I think the problem is with the gets. The form that I can't modify is sended by get, using the next url:

http://domain.com/SGAP/dades_proj_edit.php?idedit=2011854&id=&projectname=afsdfasdf&comptitle=asasfdafsdafs&codarea=ECIV&grauimp=1&codtipus=2&codsubtipus=6&subtipusdef=fdsaafasfddfs&codpais=8&clientid=2&promotor=asdfa&entfin=fsdafadsfds&impcontract=2&initdate=21%2F01%2F2011&findate=30%2F01%2F2011&uteflag=false&utepartic=&utepercent=0&descprelim=fdsadasdadfsadfs&codprojstatus=1&statusstamp=25%2F01%2F2011&cruserid=&action=update

Firefox shows a blanc page with no error. I've tried to force to show all errors with error_reporting(E_ALL) and ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL) to show if something happens but the wait page is showed with 0 errors.

I supposed that was a $_GET error and I tried to put on the top of the page and in the end of it a `<?php if($_GET["test"]) echo "Works"; ?>` and call the webpage with: domain.com/SGAP/dades_proj.edit.php?test=testing and it works from top to end... I don't know where is the error.

What I can check to figure where is the white page comming? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the page that receives the GET (dades_proj_edut.php) supposed to do and display? Have you tried printing all the GET input to the screen at the top of the page?

Comment: You say it doesn't report an error, but have you checked the server logs?

Comment: Posted in the answer: `[Tue Jan 25 10:12:49 2011] [notice] child pid 30310 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do.

Start at the top of the file/stack, and add this code:

```
<?
$myUniqueCounter = 0;
error_log(++$myUniqueCounter . ', line ' . __LINE__ );
```

Then, copy and paste the `error_log` line all over the file/stack, and see where it stops logging.

Comment: I agree, start by error_log until you see where exactly the code crashes ( you can tail -f the log file on bash and track it quickly).when you do find the crashing line you might be able to see why. Also check phpinfo() to see if anything you need in the code is disabled in your servers config

Comment: `[Tue Jan 25 10:12:49 2011] [notice] child pid 30310 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)` this is the only error I found when executing the URL from above, not exactly a error. I don't know what it means! :S

Comment: quick search turns up this: This may be caused by a conflict between php dynamically loaded modules and apache included modules.

Check out the pdo manual, uninstall either the php modules from php repository or debian repository. again I would check the modules and all that is loaded to check for inconsistencies. but something is wrong with your config. ( this is not code)

Comment: yes quick searches reveal that this is module related. look at [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-18490.html) post on ubuntu forums that shows similar problem

Comment: I'm looking on the httpd.conf and I see that ALL modules are load: http://pastebin.com/TcpAnhMJ

Comment: Good idea, but this won't work. If an error in the script is causing it to crash, the output buffers never get written, so your very helpful logging function won't be of any use unfortunately. Good idea though.

Answer (score 1):

I have occasionally seen php die without a blank output. Generally, the only way to solve this is to remove everything from the file, and then add code back in one line at a time. When it stops working, you know that whatever you just added caused the fault. You can try running php with the -l flag, to check the syntax, but this might not find the problem; the only sure way really is to just to add or remove things until the output changes.

I know this isn't much help, but there is no other way to debug the problem, short of executing php itself with a debugger... actually, you could do that; can you run php from gdb? That might help you find what is causing the issue, but no guarantees.

Comment: I've no access to the remote server. I've to call to a corporate and explain the problem and then they decide if do or not... I think I can't run php on this server with -l falg... I've seen that the apache and php are outdate, using 2.0 for apache and 5.1 for PHP. First of all, I'll ask to upgrade to 2.2 and 5.3 and see what happens. With this env works so... it will work? :(